# Is API async by default

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I am migrating an API project form .net framework to .NET 6.0. So far, methods that can be asynchronous have never been made asynchronous. One person told me that API projects are async by default, but I still find people calling async and await in those projects and I'm wondering if I should start using async or not. I am grateful to anyone who can help.

I looked at different projects and asked a person who is more familiar

Comment: There are 7 different network layers.  Being Async at one level doesn't mean it is Async at all levels.  The low level windows methods uses timers and events since the OS is multi-users which are Async.  It doesn't mean the c# methods are also Async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I should start using async or not.

In an ideal world, where you have infinite developer capability and zero shareholder demands, yes, you should use `async` wherever I/O is done.

In the real world, it's a judgement call. The majority of the time, it's cheaper to just pay for more/bigger servers than it is to pay for developers. There's also the consideration that APIs are not often the bottleneck; it's the storage backend that's the true bottleneck, and making your APIs `async` doesn't help your database scale at all.

Generally speaking, legacy code can be left alone, and new code should use `async`. You may wish to update shared code so that it supports both `async` and synchronous.